# check whether .bat file is running in windows 7

Tags: batch-file

how do I check whether  .bat file is running in windows 7.when I run it as admin I only see black window which then disappears.I don't whether it is running in the background.how do I check?? 
    it look like this

```
@echo off
SET PLAYSMS_PATH=C:\xampp\htdocs\sema.shujaa.mobi
SET PLAYSMS_BIN=C:\playsms\bin
SET PLAYSMS_LOG=C:\playsms\logs
SET PLAYSMS_SPOOL=C:\playsms\spool
SET REFRESH_RATE=2
SET PHP_CLI=C:\xampp\php\php
```

Comment: Use the Task Manager?

Answer (score 3):

What you posted does nothing useful. It sets some environmental variables and then ends (which means there's nothing to run in the background). Once it ends, the environmental variables no longer exist any longer.

In other words, running this batch file does nothing except open a console window and then close it. It doesn't matter if it's Windows 7, XP, Vista, or Windows 3.1, or whether you're running as an adminstrator, non-administrator, or anything else; it simply opens and closes a console window.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this temporary line at the end of your script to debug the output. This will wait for user input to

```
SET /P <var>=[<prompt message>]
```

or you can pipe the .bat file in a outputfile to see output like this when ranned from a command line window ( isntead of double clciking on it)

c:>`myscript.bat > mylogfile.txt`

Comment: What purpose does this serve? The variables are set and the batch file then exits, and the variables no longer exist. There's no point in preserving or examining their values, because they immediately vanish. You can read the batch file to see what they *would have* been set to, but pausing the batch file serves no purpose (and neither does redirecting to a text file).

Comment: It serves the purpose of debugging, making sure your scripts run correctly, be able to see what they actually do or break for.